# Detecting a button that is loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, html, button, asynchronous

On a web page I am looking at, there is a lot of data being loaded asynchronously.

Included with that data is a button called "View More". If you either click on the button or simply scroll right to the bottom, more data will be loaded via a "GET" call function.

When I try using this (in FireBug console):

```
document.getElementById('#button9').click();
```

or

```
document.getElementById('button9').click();
```

I get this result:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
>
> document.getElementById('#button9').click();

From what I have read about this TypeError, the Id cannot be detected, which I assume is because of the data being asynchronous. Is there a way to detect the element (it doesn't show up on the "page source" but it is there when I click on "Inspect Element with FireBug")?

I would like to detect the element and then make a call to a click event to 'simulate a click' (meaning I would like a click to take place without clicking on the button or scrolling right down) with the output being displayed in the browser (per usual).

Answer (score 0):

```
This will work, no matter even if you don't know when the object is getting created and added to the DOM 

//chrome / ff /IE
$("#button9").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    // Add click function here
});     


//IE 8 and lower 
$("#button9").bind("propertychange", function() {
   //Add click function here
});
```

**2nd Option**
**OR**
Not sure if it supposts IE8 though but it definitely  supports all others

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function (e) {
        if ($(e.target.id) == "#button9") {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }, false)
```

**Explanation:** It checks if the DOM has found an element with the specific ID, if so, execute the click function.

Comment: Option 1 gives me the same: "TypeError: $(...) is null" and Option 2 gives me an: "undefined"

Comment: for option two can you try console.log($(e.target.id)) inside if or can you post a link ?

Comment: Ani say the application is twitter.com , how would I automate the scroll-down option without scrolling down? Say I want the application to scroll down 5 times, I would use a "for" loop, but what or where could I find the actual code that makes twitter load more tweets when you scroll down?

Comment: You need to know some element `Id` or `Class` in order to execute that...The `DOMSubtreeModified function` should still work.

Comment: Turns out the problem is something called the "Same Origin Policy", as the data is being called via a GET function in an iframe from a different URL. I tried using Force CORS with your code, but it didn't work, so I will try to find a solution where "SOP" is turned off completely.

Comment: Ani, I viewed the source thoroughly and it looks like they are using JQuery for making the page auto-load. Handling a scrolling feature feels very different to a button, unless instead of: "document.getElementById('#button9').click();" I use: "document.getElementById('#id10').scroll();" . What do you think?

Comment: Make sense..But are you trying to do exactly what twitter is doing ? What's your final goal ?

Comment: My goal is to make tweets load without scrolling down. Say I am on my "Mentions" page, I just call the script and "all" my mentions load without me needing to scroll for them to load.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to attach the event, then the bottom will work.

If the problem is that it is null, and you don't know when it will show up, your best bet is to create a loop that runs until it exists.

```
var obj = document.getElementById('button9');
obj.addEventListener('click', function() {
 alert(' you clicked on ' + this);
}, false);
```

in case its that second instance, and you want to wait until the object events, then use:

```
checkExists(); 

function checkExists() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('button9');
    if (obj != null) {
        obj.addEventListener('click', function() {
             alert(' you clicked on ' + this);
        }, false);
        alert('added event');
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(checkExists, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the first option I'm getting: TypeError: "obj is null" 
"obj.addEventListener('click', function() {..." & for Option 2 I am getting: "undefined" . I also tried using different names in the getElementById, but still the same result.